# Not able to get iframe contents

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to get the contents of iframe with :

```
for thing in article_edit_soup.find("iframe", {"class":"cke_wysiwyg_frame cke_reset"}):
    for things in thing.contents:
        f.write(things.strip("\t"))
```

and it gives the error :

> TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

But I am sure I can see the iframe when I inspect the webpage.

Comment: What does `article_edit_soup.find("iframe", {"class":"cke_wysiwyg_frame cke_reset"})` output on its own?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is the `things.content` is not an Array like object. So you need to convert it into a data type that is an iterable. The way you do this depends on what your date structure is. Without seeing more of you code then the most likely answer is `Object.values(things.content)`.